# Problem with Fancyhdr, doesn't shows headers at any page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to create a document in Latex which satisfies the following features:

1. First page of each chapter, without header-body.
2. All other pages, with its respective header and footer.

But the following code, only satisfies first feature, and I want 1 and 2 at the same time. What I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\usepackage[bookmarks=true, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% First page of each chapter
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{Test 1}

\author{Just me\\ \texttt{justme@gmail.com}}

\oddsidemargin=15pt

\evensidemargin=15pt

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.7in}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{bibliography}

\include{p1}

    \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{thanks}

    \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\include{summary}

  \tableofcontents
   \thispagestyle{empty}

  \listoffigures
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \cleardoublepage

\include{p2}

 \newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anexo}

\lhead[\thepage]{CHAPTER \thechapter. \rightmark}
\rhead[CHAPTER \thechapter. \leftmark]{\thepage}

\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Regards.

Edit: code of 'p1'

```
% p1
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\begin{center}
```

`\large
    \textbf{\textcolor{BrickRed}{some title}}\\

    \textbf{\textcolor{Sepia}{type of project}}\\

\huge 
    \textbf{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{Wonderful Project Name}}

\normalsize

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{figures/logo1.png}
        \label{uv}
\end{figure}

    \textbf{AUTHOR: \textcolor{Blue}{Just me}}

    \textbf{TUTORING: \textcolor{Blue}{Charles Parrish, Maximum Codus Serratus}}

\large      

    \textbf{2015}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figures/school1.png}
        \label{school}
    \end{figure}`

\end{center}

Comment: When I clean down your code to [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), everything works fine as you want in your both points...

Comment: Hi and welcome, isn't that the standard setting?

Comment: @Johannes_B Hi, thank you! What do you mean with "standard setting"? I found documentation for fancyhdr here [FancyhdrDoc](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) and I tried to use the easier form :)

Comment: @Pouya Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, I know, it is really strange, because a minimal example works for me too. But the code I posted before, doesn't work properly (fails in point 2).

Comment: Except for making the plain pages completely empty, this seems to be the default setting of book.

Comment: We don't see the contents of the files you are including. Somewhere in there might be a `\pagestyle{empty}` (or something similar. Try commenting out all the includes, and then test by uncommenting every include individually ([more detailed instructions](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/))

Comment: Well, I have been investigating and I think that I've managed to isolate the error. All works perfect before I include 'p1'. After that, all headers dissapears. I copy the code of 'p1' (in the main post), because I can't find the error here neither :(

Comment: Look at the first/second line of file p1, what do you see? ;-) What did i say in [the comment above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/496229) to look out for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the odd behaviour of empty header/footer was suprisingly caused by `\pagestyle{empty}`.